# Is there a better way to ensure that a footer stays at the bottom of a scrollable div whose height is large enough to touch the bottom of the screen?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-position, affix

At the end of my post I provide the layout for the question.

I have a layout that has two columns, sort of, a navigation sidebar that is not always open (col0) and a main area (col1) that is always open. The main area displays content. Finally, I have a footer that sits right below the highest level of the page.

Inside the main or content area there is a transition component that presents the next routed component using CSS transitions.

What I need to do is to get the footer to be a footer, that is, to be strictly at the bottom of the **scroll position** of the screen and the containing div. That doesn't mean **fixed** because you can scroll.

I would like to do this in CSS but I cannot get it to go and I am feeling a bit tempted to have it read the height and update before the component is mounted etc. Is there a better way?

Here is a `react` `Component` `render()` function with plenty of stuff deleted for your convenience:

```
  <div style={prepareStyles(styles.heightHundred)}>
    <ChromeHelmet />
      <AppBar ... yada .../>
      <div style={prepareStyles(styles.root)}>
        <div style={prepareStyles(styles.content)}>
          <EasyTransition
            path={this.props.location.pathname}
            initialStyle={{opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-100%)'}}
            transition="opacity 0.2s ease-in, transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0.3s"
            finalStyle={{opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0%)'}}
            leaveStyle={{opacity: 0.9, transform: 'translateY(500%'}}
          >
          { this.props.children }
          </EasyTransition>
        </div>
      </div>
      <AppNavDrawer />
    <Footer
      style={prepareStyles(styles.footer)} />
  </div>
```

### Edit

When I try to use `flex` I can tell it is close **but** it has no effect because the sidebar is displayed with `position: fixed;` and some fancy CSS stuff inside the React component that I'm afraid to touch. But when I undo that `position: fixed`, the footer is where it needs to be but the sidebar is wonky obviously...

Comment: you should use flex-box layout. `display: flex; flex-flow: column: no-wrap;` on the outermost div would solve your issue

Comment: doh! I am not used to it yet... I mean I haven't yet gotten to thinking, of course,flexboxc

Comment: @JohnRuddell didn't work. I mean, I didnt do it right. Read my edit

Comment: no problem! thats what stack overflow is for :D flexbox is amazing. you should read up on what you can do with it, no more need to use floats and stuff. it also has benefits of where you want to lay the content out. so for instance in this case.. `height: 100%; display: flex; flex-flow: column no-wrap; justify-content: space-between;` is what you want

Comment: thats just because you didn't specify which way you wanted to justify the content.. see my other comment

Comment: if you cant figure it out i can do a screenshare voice chat to get it working :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell checking it out now

Comment: @JohnRuddell you were close - or I was close to describing to you the right situation - it was flex-end That i needed not between but whatever it works!

Comment: nice! space-between works when there are two elements puts the first at the top and the second at the bottom. but i misread you have three elements there so yea. I can write it up as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using flex-box layout. it is supported by most browsers (IE 10 and up, Edge, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, iOS Safari, Opera Mini, Android Browser, Chrome for Android).

just add these styles to the parent div

```
display: flex; 
flex-flow: column no-wrap; 
justify-content: space-between;
```

on the footer add

```
align-self: flex-end;
```

here is a [GREAT](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) explanation of flex and how it works. lots of really useful information here

Comment: FYI I did something slightly different without using align at all from http://transmission.vehikl.com/sticky-footer-with-flexbox/ because I think my case was simpler even

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos Ok I see what you are saying. I honestly dont really like that solution only because with that you are relying on a specific height for the footer. so on a mobile resolution you need to change the styles for the heights and everything. Flexbox doesn't need specific heights for spacing elements which is why its so nice and easy to use. if you are ok with that solution then awesome :) I can try and help you get it without specifying a height if you'd like :)

Comment: I just saw this. I'll try your solution now on a new page

Answer (score 1):

What you’re looking for is the [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).

The HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="main">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;} 
html, body {height: 100%;}
#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {
  overflow:auto;
  padding-bottom: 180px; /* must be same height as the footer */
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -180px; /* negative value of footer height */
  height: 180px;
  clear:both;
} 

/*Opera Fix thanks to Maleika (Kohoutec)*/
body:before {
  content:"";
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  width:0;
  margin-top:-32767px;/* thank you Erik J - negate effect of float*/
}
```

Comment: Let me try it out and get back to you... i'm also trying the flexbox

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos Ok

Comment: I have definitely used something like this in the past to make two divs have equal height but it is not ideal I know from experience lol a couple of funny things can happen with affixing etc

Comment: it looks like it probably will but I want to do Flexbox but if it works I'll give you the pt anyway so both ways are confirmed

Comment: it may not work depending on the fixed sidebar. still should check it before awarding the answer (for other passers by)

Comment: @JohnRuddell if you coudl answer the question ill give you the answer asnd the vote other wise i just have this answer to give both to, and this one may be good for older browsers not all suypport flexbox